# reactjs / javascript: Change padding dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, internationalization

I'm working with reactjs. When my site is in english I have padding perfect (`padding: 0 1.7em 0 0;`). However I need padding to be closer to `padding: 0 0.55em 0 0;` when the site is in German. All other languages my site is translated in fit in-between these paddings. The navbar (which is what im working on with this padding) in german has the links on 2 lines, which I cannot have under the padding of 1.7em. yet when I change it to 0.55em the english site looks too cramped. When I switch to %, the only % that works is 1%. the 1% padding for english looks super cramped, and the german site looks only okay.

Questions: 
what can I do? Is there a way to get the size of the link `<p>`'s then do a calc() in the css? or in the js? This would allow a change in each language. So maybe it would be possible by changing the state of the css... idk, im a bit new to react to know fully what im trying to convey.

Comment: That seems more of a general problem about internationalizing websites than about React.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to make your `<p>` slightly wider, since that's the easiest thing to do. Failing that:

Find the language the user has set using `window.navigator.language`

Then use react to generate a css rule for your page to obey. Make sure the rule is printed after your include all of your other styles so the padding value is not overwritten by your default settings.